# smartctl: suspend read-scan the remainder of the disk

Tags: smart, smartctl

I have started read-scan the disk using:

```
smartctl -t select,10-11 -t afterselect,on -t pending,45 /dev/sda
```

It seems, however, it kills the disk performance. I had expected that the read-scan would (just like the tests) be suspended when there was disk activity.

I had also expected the read scan (like the tests) would run without load on the server, but according to `iostat -x -d 1` it seems read-test goes through the controller.

Is this normal? Can I suspend the read scan when the disk is active (e.g. only run read scan if idle for 500 ms)?

Answer (score 2):

As per smartctl man page, you can abort non-captive test with `smartctl -X /dev/sda`. According to that page, your selective test is non-captive, because you didn't use the `-C` option.

But note that all tests do harm performance. Although they run only when the disk is idle for some time (I suspect some miliseconds), it still moves the disk heads to another position, so the disk has to seek more for real data activity. On busy server I am able to run only `short` tests, because the `long` test would take weeks and the performance would be impacted for the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to add to such an old thread, but I think it's important to note that performance of an **ssd** might not be reduced by running a selftest.  An ssd has no read-write head to move, and a selftest is presumably a lower priority task than servicing a read or write request issued by the pc.

My Windows PC has a Crucial MX500 ssd C:, and the pc runs a script nonstop that periodically runs `smartctl -t select,0-MAX -t pending,0 C:` so that ssd selftests run nearly non-stop.  The ssd performance is not reduced.

(The purpose of these selftests is to mitigate a Crucial bug that causes excessive write amplification, which correlates with a more widely known Crucial bug called "Bogus Current Pending Sectors" which you could google.  Apparently the bug's process is a lower priority background task than the selftest process, so the buggy writes by the ssd to itself occur only during the brief pauses between selftests.  The purpose of the pauses is to allow the ssd to occasionally run low priority processes that might be essential to the health of the ssd... for example, wear leveling.)

**When I ran the CrystalDiskMark benchmark with a selftest running, I found that the ssd's performance slightly exceeds the speed specs published by Crucial for a brand new MX500**.  Because the selftest prevents the ssd from entering its low power mode -- which can be deduced by observing the effect of selftests on the ssd's Power On Hours smart attribute -- my theory is that the selftest allows the ssd to save a little time by not having to switch from low power mode to normal mode when servicing a pc read or write request.